# Теория графов. Есть алгоритм поиска простого цикла в графе, но как найти все простые циклы в графе?

Tags: графы, c++

Вот для поиска простого цикла. Что нужно добавить, чтоб найти все?
[Проверка графа на ацикличность и нахождение цикла](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/finding_cycle)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm

Comment: Для поиска циклов (я правда не понимаю, какие именно нужны автору) существуют алгоритм Зайца и Черепахи, Гамильтонов и Эйлеров алгоритм (https://rep.vsu.by/handle/123456789/24352 26 страница)

Answer (score 1):

Обход в глубину, помечаешь пройденные дуги и если на них натыкаешся, то пропускаешь, делаешь возврат, дальше ищешь...